# When i add target="_blank" in my code, it still opens in the save window that it was clicked in

Tags: html, css, debugging

As i said, when i add `target="_blank"` in my code, it still opens in the save window that it was clicked in. I have tried placing the `target="_blank` in the front and in the back of the code, but i doesnt seem to get it to work. Can you help me? Here is the HTML that i am using: `

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>TacoMannen</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="\TacoSite CSS.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <br>
        <button target="_blank" class="button Kalender disabled" onclick="location.href='/kalender'" >Kalender</button>
        <button target="_blank" class="button blogg" onclick="location.href='/blogg'" >Blogg</button>
        <button target="_blank" class="button kontakt" onclick="location.href='/kontakt-meg'" >Kontakt Meg</button>
        <button target="_blank" onclick="location.href='https://www.youtube.com/channel/UC1T-CxkwZ8fLDzlmIOM2Rxw?view_as=subscriber'" type="button" >Min Kanal</button>
        <br>
    </body>

</html>
```

And here is the CSS that i am using:

```
.button {
    background-color: white;
    color: black;
    border: 2px solid #4CAF50;
}

.button:hover {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    color: white;
}
```

And a snippet if you need it:

```css
.button {
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
  border: 2px solid #4CAF50;
}

.button:hover {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>TacoMannen</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="\TacoSite CSS.css">
</head>

<body>
  <br>
  <button target="_blank" class="button Kalender disabled" onclick="location.href='/kalender'">Kalender</button>
  <button target="_blank" class="button blogg" onclick="location.href='/blogg'">Blogg</button>
  <button target="_blank" class="button kontakt" onclick="location.href='/kontakt-meg'">Kontakt Meg</button>
  <button target="_blank" onclick="location.href='https://www.youtube.com/channel/UC1T-CxkwZ8fLDzlmIOM2Rxw?view_as=subscriber'" type="button">Min Kanal</button>
  <br>
</body>

</html>
```

And if people could point out other errors that i am not aware of, that would be great :-)

Comment: Buttons don't have a target attribute, anchors do

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to use `<a>` tag and not `<button>` tag, as they don't have `target` attribute or `href`. You are instructing the page to open using JavaScript and not the normal `href`. You have two options:

1. Change it to `<a href="">`.

   ```
   <a target="_blank" class="button Kalender disabled" href="/kalender">Kalender</a>
   ```
2. Use `window.open` for the `<button>`.

   ```
   <button class="button Kalender disabled" onclick="window.open('/kalender');" >Kalender</button>
   ```